# How to convert json from array of properties

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I was wondering if there is any out of the box functionality to convert the following json to an object or do I need to develop my own deserializer for this type of JSON object?

```json
{
   "Fields":[
      "Code",
      "Name"
   ],
   "Records":[
      [
         "JD",
         "Jhon Doe"
      ],
      [
         "JJ",
         "Jhon Joe"
      ]
   ]
}
```

The object

```
public class Response
{
    public string[] Fields { get; set; }
    public Something[] Records { get; set; }
}

public class Something {
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0.  Ff your not using dotnet core their is https://www.newtonsoft.com/json.  That should work.

Comment: Can we assume that each and every record array contains two strings?

Comment: @PeterCsala no, the `Fields[]` specifies the fields and the order.

Comment: Then no there is no such out-of-the-box solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing that there is no "out of the box" option and using Martin Simecek approach.
Decided to convert the record array to `string[][]` type and create the following method.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the record array as an object of type T
    /// </summary>
    public T[] RecordsAsEntity()
    {
        /* The result array of generic type T */
        var result = new T[Records.Length];
        
        /*
         * The field array specifies the property name and order
         * of the records.
         * Iterate each record and using reflection create a new
         * instance and populate the respective property with the
         * value.
         * We need to unsure that: fields.length == records[].length
         */
        var type = typeof(T);
        for (int i = 0; i < Records.Length; i++)
        {
            var record = Records[i];

            /* Create a new T instance */
            var obj = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

            /* Iterate the columns */
            for (int j = 0; j < Fields.Length; j++)
            {
                var propertyName = Fields[j];

                /* Set the value of the repective property */
                var prop = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
                prop.SetValue(obj, record[j]);

            }

            /* Save the created instance in the result array */
            result[i] = obj;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

The previous method does not include several validation rules. Pay attention that this method only supports string properties and trusts that the property name always exists.

Comment: Even though this approach might work, but it's quite error prone. What if `Fields` contains a name which does not a related property? Most probably you might receive a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: @PeterCsala I did not include all the validation because it is made in another section of my service. But I'll mention it in the answer thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part is, I guess, the fact that you're getting `Records` as array of string arrays, so there's no mapping to `Code` and `Name` respectively.

If you could work without the `Code` and `Name` properties in your result object, you could define it like this:

```
public class Response
{
    public string[] Fields { get; set; }
    public string[][] Records { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use `JsonSerializer` in .NET 5+ like this:

```
using System.Text.Json;
...
var res = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Response>(sourceText);
```

Or [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) like this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
...
var res2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(sourceText);
```

Comment: This is not a solution to my problem; I cannot work without those properties.